# maybe matrix plot!

Tags: matlab

for an implicit equation(name it "y") of lambda and beta-bar which is plotted with "ezplot" command, i know it is possible that by a root finding algorithm like "bisection method", i can find solutions of beta-bar for each increment of lambda. but how to build such an algorithm to obtain the lines correctly.
(i think solutions of beta-bar should lie in an n*m matrix)
would you in general show the methods of plotting such problem? thanks.
one of my reasons is discontinuity of "ezplot" command for my equation.
ok here is my pic:
 [alt text http://www.mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-view-05.php?id=5039TE-beta-bar-L-n2-.png](http://www.mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-view-05.php?id=5039TE-beta-bar-L-n2-.png)

or
[http://www.mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-05/5039TE-beta-bar-L-n2-.png](http://www.mojoimage.com/)
[Free Image Hosting](http://www.mojoimage.com/)
and my code (in short):

```
h=ezplot('f1',[0.8,1.8,0.7,1.0]);
```

and in another m.file

```
function y=f1(lambda,betab)
n1=1.5; n2=1; z0=120*pi;
d1=1; d2=1;  a=1;
k0=2*pi/lambda;
u= sqrt(n1^2-betab^2);
wb= sqrt(n2^2-betab^2);
uu=k0*u*d1;
wwb=k0*wb*d2 ;
z1=z0/u;  z1_b=z1/z0;
a0_b=tan(wwb)/u+tan(uu)/wb;
b0_b=(1/u^2-1/wb^2)*tan(uu)*tan(wwb);
c0_b=1/(u*wb)*(tan(uu)/u+tan(wwb)/wb);
uu0= k0*u*a; m=0;
y=(a0_b*z1_b^2+c0_b)+(a0_b*z1_b^2-c0_b)*...
cos(2*uu0+m*pi)+b0_b*z1_b*sin(2*uu0+m*pi);
end
```

fzero cant find roots; it says "Function value must be real and finite".
anyway, is it possible to eliminate discontinuity and only plot real zeros of y?
heretofore,for another function (namely fTE), which is :

```
function y=fTE(lambda,betab,s)
m=s;
n1=1.5;    n2=1;
d1=1;   d2=1;   a=1; 
z0=120*pi; 
k0=2*pi/lambda;
u = sqrt(n1^2-betab^2);  
w = sqrt(betab^2-n2^2);           
U = k0*u*d1;   
W = k0*w*d2 ;     
z1 = z0/u;             z1_b = z1/z0; 
a0_b = tanh(W)/u-tan(U)/w;
b0_b = (1/u^2+1/w^2)*tan(U)*tanh(W);
c0_b = -(tan(U)/u+tanh(W)/w)/(u*w);
U0 = k0*u*a;
y = (a0_b*z1_b^2+c0_b)+(a0_b*z1_b^2-c0_b)*cos(2*U0+m*pi)...
+ b0_b*z1_b*sin(2*U0+m*pi);
end
```

i'd plotted real zeros of "y" by these codes:

```
s=0;  % s=0 for even modes and s=1 for odd modes.
lmin=0.8;       lmax=1.8;
bmin=1;            bmax=1.5;
lam=linspace(lmin,lmax,1000);
for n=1:length(lam)
    increment=0.001;  tolerence=1e-14; xstart=bmax-increment;
    x=xstart;
    dx=increment;
    m=0;   
    while x > bmin
        while dx/x >= tolerence
            if fTE(lam(n),x,s)*fTE(lam(n),x-dx,s)<0
                dx=dx/2;
            else
                x=x-dx;
            end
        end
        if abs(real(fTE(lam(n),x,s))) < 1e-6    %because of discontinuity some answers are not correct.%
            m=m+1;
            r(n,m)=x;
        end
        dx=increment;
        x=0.99*x;
    end
end
figure
hold on,plot(lam,r(:,1),'k'),plot(lam,r(:,2),'c'),plot(lam,r(:,3),'m'),
xlim([lmin,lmax]);ylim([1,1.5]),
xlabel('\lambda(\mum)'),ylabel('\beta-bar')
```

you see i use matrix to save data for this plot.

![alt text][2]
because here lines start from left(axis) to rigth. but if the first line(upper) starts someplace from up to rigth(for the first figure and f1 function), then i dont know how to use matrix. lets improve this method.

[2]: [http://www.mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-05/2812untitled.png](http://www.mojoimage.com/)
[Free Image Hosting](http://www.mojoimage.com/)

Comment: Use the “image” button (the sixth one in the toolbar).

Comment: And post some code too.  How do you expect us to help you write Matlab without showing us what you have already written ?

Comment: It would really help to see the equations you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html) will display discontinuities because there *really are* discontinuities or some form of complicated behavior of the function occurring there. You can see this by generating your plot in an alternative way using the [CONTOUR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html) function.

You should first modify your `f1` function by replacing the [arithmetic operators](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) (`*`, `/`, and `^`) with their element-wise equivalents (`.*`, `./`, and `.^`) so that `f1` can accept matrix inputs for `lambda` and `betab`. Then, run the code below:

```
lambda = linspace(0.8,1.8,500);  %# Create a vector of 500 lambda values
betab = linspace(0.7,1,500);     %# Create a vector of 500 betab values
[L,B] = meshgrid(lambda,betab);  %# Create 2-D grids of values
y = f1(L,B);                     %# Evaluate f1 at every point in the grid
[c,h] = contour(L,B,y,[0 0]);    %# Plot contour lines for the value 0
set(h,'Color','b');              %# Change the lines to blue
xlabel('\lambda');                                   %# Add an x label
ylabel('$\overline{\beta}$','Interpreter','latex');  %# Add a y label
title('y = 0');                                      %# Add a title
```

And you should see the following plot:

[image]

Notice that there are now additional lines in the plot that did not appear when using [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html), and these lines are very jagged. You can zoom in on the crossing at the top left and make a plot using [SURF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html) to get an idea of what's going on:

```
lambda = linspace(0.85,0.95,100);  %# Some new lambda values
betab = linspace(0.95,1,100);      %# Some new betab values
[L,B] = meshgrid(lambda,betab);    %# Create 2-D grids of values
y = f1(L,B);                       %# Evaluate f1 at every point in the grid
surf(L,B,y);                       %# Make a 3-D surface plot of y
axis([0.85 0.95 0.95 1 -5000 5000]);                 %# Change the axes limits
xlabel('\lambda');                                   %# Add an x label
ylabel('$\overline{\beta}$','Interpreter','latex');  %# Add a y label
zlabel('y');                                         %# Add a z label
```

[image]

Notice that there is a lot of high-frequency periodic activity going on along those additional lines, which is why they look so jagged in the contour plot. This is also why a very *general* utility like [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html) was displaying a break in the lines there, since it really isn't designed to handle specific cases of complicated and poorly behaved functions.

**EDIT: (response to comments)**

These additional lines may not be true zero crossings, although it is difficult to tell from the [SURF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html) plot. There may be a discontinuity at those lines, where the function shoots off to `-Inf` on one side of the line and `Inf` on the other side of the line. When rendering the surface or computing the contour, these points on either side of the line may be mistakenly connected, giving the false appearance of a zero crossing along the line.

If you want to find a zero crossing given a value of `lambda`, you can try using the function [FZERO](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fzero.html) along with an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) to turn your function of two variables `f1` into a function of one variable `fcn`:

```
lambda_zero = 1.5;             %# The value of lambda at the zero crossing
fcn = @(x) f1(lambda_zero,x);  %# A function of one variable (lambda is fixed)
betab_zero = fzero(fcn,0.94);  %# Find the value of betab at the zero crossing,
                               %#   using 0.94 as an initial guess
```

Comment: thanks.
but how to extract values of beta-bar for a given lambda(like lambda=1.5)?

Comment: something else.
why when i use root finding method to find beta-bars for a range of lambda, the additional lines dont show themselves?

Comment: @Alireza: I updated my answer to address your comments. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: i updated my question, because of character limitation in comments.

Comment: in fact, in matrix "r", each column is a line in the second Fig.
but for the first function "fTE", beta-bar is decreasing in the first column. but when lambda reaches more than 1.1, beta-bar become more than previous ones and hereafter the first column must be cut and a new one(the next column) should be created.

Comment: @Alireza: I haven't yet had a chance to work through the newest part you added to your question. I'll let you know when I do.

Comment: would you say that it is possible developing this way or not.

Comment: @Alireza: You changed some things in your last edit. You are using a different function `fTE` with slightly different equations, and I don't know what the justification is for the changes. Are the new equations somehow a modified version of the previous ones? Also, you are plotting over a different range of beta values in your second plot. Is this intentional?

Comment: the first fig. is for "f1". but i said that the last edited code(finding zeros algorithm), which i want to use for f1, is just applicable for "fTE". how can i manipulate the code(finding zeros algorithm) to be usable for "fTE"?

Comment: in fact, the lines plotted with "fTE" and with "f1" must be (and are)continuous.
because of different ranges, we have different functions("f1" & "fTE", due to physical justifications). (each range has its own function)

Comment: @gnovice don't have any idea?

Comment: @Alireza: I've tried a few things, but haven't yet been able to figure out a better algorithm to remove the false roots that works for both `f1` and `fTE`. I'll update my answer when/if I manage figure it out.

Comment: dont u discover any new thing?